# HAC standard errors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have the task of obtaining HAC standard error tests from MATLAB.

I start with a point and click estimation software, and obtain the output, see below:

```
Linear Regression - Estimation by Least Squares
With Quadratic Spectral Standard Errors, Bandwidth    1.000
Dependent Variable Y1
Usable Observations                       245
Degrees of Freedom                        243
Centered R^2                        0.0079741
R-Bar^2                             0.0038917
Uncentered R^2                      0.0189519
Mean of Dependent Variable       0.0095039657
Std Error of Dependent Variable  0.0900283623
Standard Error of Estimate       0.0898530111
Sum of Squared Residuals         1.9618759548
Log Likelihood                       243.7113
Durbin-Watson Statistic                2.0163

    Variable                        Coeff      Std Error      T-Stat      Signif
************************************************************************************
1.  Y1{1}                       0.147280466  0.119275464      1.23479  0.21690768
2.  Y2{1}                      -0.013577620  0.136426183     -0.09952  0.92072258
```

My attempt to 'replicate' this in MATLAB was to use the following code:

clc;
clear;

```
 data = xlsread('mydata');
    T = size(data,1);
    maxLag = floor(4*(T/100)^(2/9));
    XL = lagmatrix(data,1);
    Y = data;
    XL(1,:)=[];
    Y(1,:)=[];
    [~,seHH] = hac(XL(:,[1:2]),Y(:,1),'intercept',false,'weights','QS','bandwidth',1,'display','full')
```

The standard errors using the MATLAB output are:

```
0.116490674084335
0.132412767952969
```

Compared to the point and click estimates:

```
0.119275464
0.136426183
```

Is there something wrong with my MATLAB code?

Here is a link to the documentation:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/econ/change-bandwidth-in-newey-west-coefficient-covariance-estimate.html

Comment: This is equal up to the third significant digit. Didn't you simply click slightly off-target? Or there might be internal differences in the numerical implementation leading to small errors.

Comment: Yes but depending on the bandwidth, the difference can be significant, I was wondering if anyone had any idea that the MATLAB code was correct or not